# Stack Exchange "all site" list is random

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-exchange

The list of Stack Exchange topic sites that shows up when clicking on the Stack Exchange icon at the top left of screen seems to be randomly generated every time you change pages (even on the same board). Which is a little annoying, because it means I have to search through the entire list every time I want to switch boards.

If this is intentional, what is the reason? If it isn't then I would consider it a bug.

Comment: D'oh thanks for fixing the title, late night dyslexia I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is intentional, otherwise the first 5 sites would get visited the most.