# Stack Exchange allsites tab

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stack Exchange  “all site” list is random](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68697/stack-exchange-all-site-list-is-random)

Why are the sites in the "all sites" tab shown in a different order every time a page is refreshed? It is difficult to find an specific site.

[image]

Comment: [It is in random order.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68697/stack-exchange-all-site-list-is-random)

Comment: @Jeff M Why is it random?

Comment: To make it more likely for people to visit other sites who use that list rather than the ones shown at the top of the list.  The same reason why answers with the same vote count are listed in random order.

Answer (score 0):

The order is random, as [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68697/stack-exchange-all-site-list-is-random) shows, but as to the 'I can't find the site I need' problem, I've built a small script that adds a search box to the 'All Sites' interface:

```
var container = $('<div>').css({
    background: '#ccc'
}).prependTo('#seContainerSites');

$('<input>', {
    id: 'se-site-search'
}).bind('input', function(){
    if(this.value){
        var v = this.value;
        $('#seContainerSites .itemBox').css('display', function(){
            return $(this).text().indexOf(v) !== -1 ? 'block' : 'none';
        });
     } else {
        $('#seContainerSites .itemBox').show();
     }
}).width(265).css({
    border: 0,
    fontSize: 10,
    padding: 2,
    color: '#666',
    fontWeight: 'bold'
}).appendTo(container);
```

If you want to, I can prettify it up and package it into a userscript.

Comment: Thank you. But I'm new in meta. How do I install that script?

Comment: @Enrique Well, you can't because the code isn't complete - which is why am asking you whether you need it or not